# Generator job failing on object property default

Tags: qooxdoo

I have an OpenLayers object that I'm trying to change that has the name default as one of it's properties. The Qooxdoo generator script does not like this. Is there a way to ignore this error?

I tried:

```
/**
 * @ignore default
 */
```

Here is the object in question:

```
vectorLayer.styleMap.styles.default.defaultStyle.fillColor="#FFFFFF"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

default is one of JavaScript's reserved words. Those aren't supposed to be used as identifiers, and the Generator enforces this restriction. You can work around it by using the bracket notation:

```
vectorLayer.styleMap.styles["default"].defaultStyle.fillColor="#FFFFFF"
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel! That's a nice trick! I was actually surprised that OpenLayers used that reserved word as an object property!